# How can I specify an exact output size for my networkx graph?

Tags: python, image, networkx

[image: http://imgur.com/7wiRw.png]

The above is the output of my current graph. However, I have yet to manage what I am trying to achieve. I need to output my graph in a larger size so that each node/edge can be viewed with ease.

I've tried `nx.draw(G, node_size=size)`, but that only increases the size of the nodes, not the distance between nodes and edges.

Answer (score 99):

You could try either smaller nodes/fonts or larger canvas.  Here is a way to do both:

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.cycle_graph(80)
pos = nx.circular_layout(G)

# default
plt.figure(1)
nx.draw(G,pos)

# smaller nodes and fonts
plt.figure(2)
nx.draw(G,pos,node_size=60,font_size=8) 

# larger figure size
plt.figure(3,figsize=(12,12)) 
nx.draw(G,pos)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 19):

Since it seems that your network layout is too "messy", you might want to try different graph layout algorithms and see which one suits you best.

```
nx.draw(G)  
nx.draw_random(G)  
nx.draw_circular(G)  
nx.draw_spectral(G)  
nx.draw_spring(G)
```

Also, if you have too many nodes (let's say some thousands) visualizing your graph can be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

you can increase the size of the plot as well as set the dpi.
If dpi is lowered that nodes would spread out more.

```
G = nx.Graph()
# Add edges
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(200, 80), dpi=60)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_weight='normal')
```