# Non overlapping nodes in python?

Tags: python, nodes

How do I convert this to a spaced-out and cleaner version? Where the nodes are much more far apart and non overlapping.
[image: Image of graph obtained]

```
g = nx.read_edgelist('Input.txt', nodetype=str,
  data=(('weight',int),), create_using=nx.DiGraph())
pos = nx.spring_layout(g, k=50)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(g,pos,
        width=5,alpha=1,edge_color='orange')
nx.draw(g,pos,with_labels=True)
labels = {e: g.edges[e]['weight'] for e in g.edges}
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(g,pos,edge_labels=labels)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The nodes aren't overlapping in that picture. And based on a glance at the connectivity of that graph, I'd hazard a guess it's non-planar, which means there's no way to avoid having edges that overlap.

Comment: Perhaps the user is looking for non-overlapping edge labels?  In any case, the first thing I'd try is to [adjust the figure size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567018/how-can-i-specify-an-exact-output-size-for-my-networkx-graph).